# How to build a private "Google Apps Marketplace" apps for gmail intergration like Rapportive does

Tags: gmail, integration, google-apps

Google Apps Marketplace (http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/) has enabled contextual gadgets so I could integrate my functionality in gmail. I would like to do so but I don't want to publish the app. Is this possible? (http://developer.googleapps.com/marketplace/getting-started tells me I have to become a vendor.) If I can do so I can't find any example code how to integrate in gmail, e.x. access a message, add a button, ... BTW: Greasemonkey is NOT an option.

Answer (score 1):

[Rapportive](http://rapportive.com) actually allows you to build custom contextual apps (called "Raplets") that users can integrate into the sidebar.  Raplets don't have to be released publicly (although they can be) and can access public or private data.

We have a couple of Google Groups where you can find the documentation:

- [raplet-announce](http://groups.google.com/group/raplet-announce)
  is a low-traffic list for announcing updates to the Raplet platform.
- [raplet-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/raplet-dev) is a discussion list for Raplet developers.

I'm not sure what sort of functionality you want to integrate, but if we don't support your use case yet, get in touch and we may be able to help.

*Disclosure: I'm a co-founder of Rapportive.  Apologies for the quasi-advertisement, but it is relevant to the question asked.  Made this answer community wiki to defuse the bias.*

Comment: I like the idea of an JSON-endpoint on my server which is used by Rapportive. A wonderful idea. But sadly Raplets just transmit the email and twitter id not more. From your documentation:

http://localhost:8080/raplet.php?email=rahul@rapportive.com&name=Rahul%20Vohra&twitter_username=rahulvohra&callback=jsonp123456789

Access to the email body itself is key in my business scenario. Your service is a good start, please go further. My wishes: a) Send EMail body (A REST interface would be great for this amount of data.) b) Send at least the email title! c) Allow to prepare an email replay.

Comment: @Hans: unfortunately we don't support those things at the moment.  (By "replay" I assume you mean "reply"?  I'm not sure what you mean by "preparing a reply".)  We'll bear it in mind as we may expand what information we send to Raplets, but I can't guarantee it at this point.

Comment: Yes, "reply", sorry. Well, if you want to position Rapportive in a business words and not just for fun applications a GMail CRM integration has to get access to emails and all sort of informations. And I would like to prepare email replies by your software for automated offers for example. Outlook for examples offers so many informations for CRM solutions. So honestly right now Rappportive doesn't help me at all because just extracting the email address is to less to be productive and you can hardly call this "CRM".

Comment: I do appreciate that there are important use cases which don't work unless you can access the email contents - though some people have created some very useful (and popular) Raplets that integrate with CRM systems using the information we do provide.  We'd like to be able to support the more advanced use cases, but there are tricky issues of privacy, security and user expectation (people are rightly conservative about who can read their email!).  If you're on our announcement list we'll definitely let you know if we come up with good solutions to these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "Gmail Contextual Gadgets" ( http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/contextual/ ) is what you are really looking for. You can go the direct route; Rapportive is not necessary. Examples are given here: http://www.socialtimes.com/2009/08/15-useful-gmail-sidebar-gadgets-you-wont-find-in-labs/. A short introduction is given in this Google IO video: http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/deep-dive-gmail-contextual-gadgets.html.